# How is debugging with breakpoints different from debugging with console.log?

Tags: javascript, ajax, debugging, testing, breakpoints

I could be wrong, but I believe the gist of breakpoints is to pause the state of an application, and review it's previous/current state, and cycle through each "breakpoint", to identify holes, bugs, and irregularities.

I was never taught to use this, and I believe I fall into a much more primitive, yet common, approach of debugging. Console.logs. Console.logs everywhere.

To me, a "breakpoint" is the equivalent of placing a console.log at the location where a "breakpoint" should occur, to understand the state of a particular object/class/etc.

Something tells me however, this is far from ideal, and I am lacking what appears to be a very valuable skill in debugging. Everyone that I know who is a talented developer, professor, and manager seem to heavily lean on breakpoints, yet from googling I can't find any solid explanations on how to use them to a degree superior than simple console logs.

This question is hoping to get the answer on how to differentiate the "console logger" mentality from what appears to be a more advanced form of debugging: breakpoints.

P.S. I tagged javascript and ajax as this is what I use, and my question is primarily geared towards these two categories, however I am confident this applies to all languages, and a general culture of optimal debugging.

Comment: a) you can set breakpoints without having to alter the code (and possibly recompile) b) you can *break* current execution and inspect arbitrary parts of the program state c) you can step through individual statements instead of having to reconstruct control flow from the limited (or overwhelming) outputs of your logging

Comment: Yeah so I "get" this from a purely contextual perspective, but in practice, how do I actually gather all this data without console logs? Meaning.... the state of the app doesn't tell me much unless I have a full state handler / extension to portray it (e.g. redux view), but aside for that, it's difficult to discern the current state, and what I'm looking for? Again, I'm not saying you're wrong, I'm suggesting I have a lack of understanding in how to use this, which I believe is limiting my debugging capability.

Comment: The debugger will show you the plain data structures. You don't need anything to print or "portray" the state. You can inspect the values of any variables at any point of execution. When searching for a bug, you just look at those that you suspect of being erroneous - just like you currently would log them, but much quicker and simpler.